# Custom Master page for mysite

Tags: mysite

What does it take to have the my site host web application using a custom developed master page

1. Can it be done using angular?

I have tried the SharePoint designer but that did not help.

your assistance will be highly appreciated.

Comment: yes you can use angular and SharePoint designer.